# Spring transaction doesn't rollback with exception

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, exception, rollback, spring-transactions

**Config.xml**

```
<bean id="emfactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" ref="default"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdaptor">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdaptor"/>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">com.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.SQLServer2012CustomDialect</prop>
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emfactory"/>
</bean>
```

**Service.java**

```
@Transactional
public void save(Dto dto) throws Exception{
    dao.save(entity);
    throw new Exception();
}
```

My problem is this exception does not rollback transaction. I have searched a lot and found that spring rollback transaction for runtime/unchecked exceptions by default. I have tried as following;

```
@Transactional
public void save(Dto dto) throws Exception{
    dao.save(entity);
    throw new RunTimeException();
}
```

This is working fine but it is not always in code those throws runtime exception everywhere. So, I do dig up and found rollbackFor as following;

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public void save(Dto dto) throws Exception{
    dao.save(entity);
    throw new Exception();
}
```

Now I have to change all of my codes to change @Transactional with rollbackFor. But any other way to change all @Transaction advice property to rollbackFor = Exception.class ?

Comment: dao.save(entity); Is your dao class marked as transactional ?

Comment: Yeah. In some places.

Comment: @NiravShah, please check update. with transactional at DAO.save its workinh fine now if i make my service save transactional to rollbackFor Exception.class.

Comment: if dao.save() has been marked as transactional then once a dao.save() method execution will be completed it will commit the transaction. If you remove transaction from dao.save() method then it will use transaction given by calling method & it will rollback/commit transaction once calling method has been completed.

Comment: Nope I have tested it. Both dao and service method has transactional and when service rollbacks than dao rollbacks too.

Comment: yes you are correct, What i was doing is I was calling two different dao method which has been marked transactional & one of the method throws exception then no roll back is happing & my calling method is not marked as transactional.

Comment: calling method should be marked as transactional and with that inside method transactional become no issues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124856/discussion-between-nirav-shah-and-tanjim-rahman).

Comment: I see all the effort that you have tried to implement rollback transaction when an exception occur. If you write code and try to check instantly you need to restart the server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look also at the red rectangle in the image:

[image]

With `@Transactional` The default is to *rollback only unchecked exceptions, checked exception won't rollback* **by default**.

**This might solve your problem:** (Look at the red rectangle)

[image]

You suppose to pass an array of classes to this attribute, then you should write it like this:

`@Transactional(rollbackFor = new Class[]{Exception.class})`

and **not** like you wrote it:

`@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)`

**Now, if you want to rollback checked exceptions without specifying the `rollbackFor` property**, you'll have to add XML configuration, to your configuration file. Like this:

```
<tx:advice id="txAdvice">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="*" rollback-for="Throwable"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```

Add this to your configuration XML file. The above will rollback checked exceptions.

Comment: I know this and I have did it before throw this question. Check my updated question. Is there any way to change my all @transaction property with rollbackFor Exception class at single shot??

Comment: Do you want to use the @Transactional annotation without specifying the rollbackfor attribute, and still that it'll rollback for checked exceptions?

Comment: Look at the edit answer, does it solve your problem?

Comment: Yeah earlier you have mentioned that in spring doc. I have checked it for Exception but did not work. Let me check for Throwable. But I don't think it will work.

Comment: checked but not worked. However I will up you because I didn't know this before.

Comment: Try this also: <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124865/discussion-between-tanjim-rahman-and-moshe-arad).